# Error CS0308 The non-generic method 'ICollection<ServiceDescriptor>.Add(ServiceDescriptor)' cannot be used with type arguments in my Startup.cs

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlkata

Recently I am working on with SqlKATA Query Builder. I followed steps stated in [here](https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/setup). After solving some errors, when there was no red underline situation in my code, I ran my solution. Then I received error CS0308. When I tried to troubleshoot my solution, I commented a section from Startup.cs where I locate it in ConfigureServices method:

`services.Add<QueryFactory>(() => { 
var connection = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=serverName\serverInstance;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True");
var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
return new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);
});`

After that, it ran smoothly with a displayed text I set. But when I uncommented the section, it showed me the error again.

Any ideas why? Any help would be much appreciated!
**EDITED:** 
`var connection = new SqlConnection( "Data Source=serverName\\serverInstance;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True");`

Comment: "Data Source=serverName\serverInstance;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True"  maybe this won't compile? maybe you need to escape the backslash?

Comment: @ranton187 corrected that..but it still didn't work.

Comment: `Add` method isn`t generic, even in generic collections, so rewrite it as `services.Add(()=>{` and the rest is exactly the same.

Comment: @Alejandro tried that. When I ran it, I received a new error: CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceDescriptor' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: _"The non-generic method 'ICollection<ServiceDescriptor>.Add(ServiceDescriptor)' cannot be used with type arguments"_ means that non generic method `services.Add(ServiceDescriptor)` cannot be used with type arguments like this: `services.Add<QueryFactory>(..)`

Comment: @vasily.sib So I shouldn't put `services.Add<QueryFactory>(..)` ?

Comment: I don't know, it's your code. Exception says that your `services` object do not have generic `Add` method. If it is so, then sure, you shouldn't call a method that does not exist.

Comment: Are you using **asp.net core**? The link you reference is using asp.net core and it seems you are either not using it or you are using another `Add` method which is not the one used in the link. The one in the link is a generic method and it takes a delegate but the `Add` method you are using is different. There is nothing wrong with your code. The issue is you are using the wrong DLLs or namespace but I do not have your project with all the references so I could not help you. So instead of trying to fix your code, fix your references and namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still relevant but the way I got to inject the QueryFactory object into my Query handler via constructor DI was like this in Startup.cs - ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddScoped(factory =>
        {
            return new QueryFactory
            {
                Compiler = new SqlServerCompiler(),
                Connection = new SqlConnection(connStr),
                Logger = compiled => Console.WriteLine(compiled)
            };
        });
```

PS: This is .NET Core